# Error with add method for vector in Inventory.h

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

Hey i set up a header and a .cpp file for my inventory.  Im using a vector.  I cant use anyof the push/ or pop methods that come in the vector library.  I want to use them in the main.  Also i am gettin 3 errors to do with the add method i made so that i could add to the vector in the main.

Can anyone help me to understand why i cant use the vectors functions and why i am getting these errors.

Here is my code:
**Inventory.h**

```
 #ifndef INVENTORY_H
    #define INVENTORY_H
    #include <string>


class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    std:: string add(string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
private:
    //Data members
    };


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
 #include "Inventory.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
    #include <string>


using namespace std;
vector<string> inventory;
vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;


Inventory::Inventory()
{

}

string Inventory :: add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}

void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
char input[80];
    cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(invent == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }


}
void Inventory:: displayInventory()
{
//vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "\n******Inventory******";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

**Errors**

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error C2511: 'std::string Inventory::add(std::string)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Inventory'    c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 19  1   MaroonedCA2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the header, and you lack of `using namespace std`. I *never, ever* use this command. I think it's must better to be explicit with your namespaces, and you will avoid issues like this.

```
// Compiler knows what std::string is, but not string on it's own.
std:: string add(string item);
```

If it was my project, I would remove the `using namespace std` and use `std::` everywhere.

Furthermore, you're not using your class properly. You have member methods that are operating on global variables in the .cpp file.

```
vector<string> inventory;
```

Should be a a *private member* of the `Inventory` class.

**Iterarors**

To address your comments, what I'm trying to say is that you don't need to declare iterators like that to use them, unless you need to *store* an iterator for later use (for some reason. Although can be dangerous when iterators are invalidated). Here are a few ways you can use them.

**typedef**

Using typedefs makes your life easier.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
typedef StringVec::iterator StringVecIter;
```

Now you can use them in loops.

```
for(StringVecIter it = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); ++it)
{ ... }
```

**auto**

An easier way to do these loops, is with the `auto` keyword. The compiler assign the appropriate type to the variable, which in this case is `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`

```
for(auto it = inventory.begin(); it != inventory.end(); ++it)
{ ... }
```

Comment: You would only need to move the `vector` into the class if the app needs to support multiple inventories.  With the way it is currently implemented, there is a single inventory, but there could be multiple `Inventory` instances that share that common inventory. In which case, I would change `Inventory` into a singleton so there can only be one instance running.

Comment: Im just after doing this and i get errors when i move iter etc... into the private of the header file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - If it was intended to be shared I would make it a static member. If there was only one instance to exist, I agree with you on the Singleton Pattern.

Comment: @Pendo826 - You don't even use the iterators, and unless there is a really good reason to save your iterators, you may as well create them on the fly.

Comment: @Aesthete - Im using iterators so that i can let the user interact with the vector.  Add,drop, change size etc... and mainly to move to a position in the middle if needs be.

Comment: @Aesthete  This was the way i was shown how to use a vector.  Im not really a c++ person and i am not doubting that you are right by the way.

Comment: @Pendo826: The point Aesthete was trying to make is that you don't need to declare global iterator variables at the same time you declare the vector itself. You should declare and use iterator variables on an as-needed basis instead.

Comment: @Pendo826: if you are getting errors, then you are not using them correctly.

Comment: @Pendo826 - I added some information about iterators you might find useful.

Comment: @Aesthete  That code is very useful.  I just used it and its easy to get to the middle of the vector.  Thanks i appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

`string` is from `std` namespace

change

```
std::string add(string item);
```

to

```
std::string add(std::string item);
```

A few places can be enhanced:

1. in Inventory.cpp, it's better not to `using namespace std;`, provide full namespace for variables like `std::vector`, `std::string` etc.
2. `vector<string> inventory;` can be moved inside Inventory calss

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `using namespace std;` statement (you should never use that!) and properly qualify the namespaced items that you are using, eg:

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <string>

class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    std::string add(std::string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
private:
    //Data members
};

#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> inventory;

Inventory::Inventory()
{
}

std::string Inventory::add(std::string item)
{
    inventory.push_back(item);
    return item;
}

void Inventory::showInventory()
{
    char input[80];
    std::cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if (strcmp(input, inventoryRequest) == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }
}

void displayInventoryItem(const std::string &item)
{
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}

void Inventory::displayInventory()
{
    std::cout << "You have " << inventory.size() << " items." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "******Inventory******" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Your items:" << std::endl;
    std::for_each(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), displayInventoryItem);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your inventory, myIterator, and Iter inside your class Inventory.

Comment: People already suggested this before ... and, this does not answer the question in any way.